# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for statisticians
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2333).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Need datasets? Request anything at Open Data]

Answer (score 12):

[image: World Statistics Day 2015]

Comment: This can arguably be deleted now …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Perhaps--but the site is still worth visiting.

Comment: @whuber the site is down, the domain is probably deleted.

Comment: @AdamO I have no problem linking to it!

Comment: @whuber hmm! not sure why it went fubar, probably on my end. Nevermind.

Answer (score 10):

[image: StackStats Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: so how do I use this in a tweet?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Internet Support for Statistics Software]

Comment: Our wiki is hard to find, maybe a community promotion add banner for it?

Comment: Ha, this is nice!

Comment: ... except that many of the questions will be off-topic!

Comment: @NickCox yes, but this is another reason why visible and direct link to better resources is crucial for such questions not to appear so often.

Comment: @Nick the banner above links to our meta page with resources; the idea would be to channel more of those questions directly to the list of resources.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Steve Pierson at the ASA writes, "*This is Statistics* is introducing high-school students and college undergraduates to careers in statistics as well as the importance of being statistically literate in today’s competitive jobs market. ... We also ask you to follow the campaign on your personal Twitter and Facebook accounts. Doing so is a great way to keep up to date and to share its messages with your social media networks. ... We’d of course also welcome your recommendations/advice for this campaign."

Comment: This is a cool site! Tks,

Answer (score 4):

[image: Government statistics section 2016 Data Challenge]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Learn probability & statistics online for free]

Comment: A lot of people who come here need a solid overview of the basics. The Khan Academy videos are online (i.e., convenient), free, & high-quality.

Comment: Khan academy stats&prob is often poor, so please help vote this down!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I've only ever seen a couple of them, but they were very basic & the kind of info that's standard in stats 101. Are there problems with them? I can delete this, if KA videos would likely lead people astray.

Comment: They are very traditional, and a little to much of "this is how to plug into that formula", not about conceptual understanding.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, that seems reasonable, based on what I've seen. But that is what most stats 101 classes are like as far as I can tell (not mine, though ;-). I think that may be a decent, & necessary, place for many people to start, especially some of the people who come to CV & are not even anywhere near square 1.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: I don't think you are violating any rules here, @sepideh. On meta.CV, down votes just signal disagreement (i.e., that people don't want to use this as one of our community ads), not that you are doing something wrong.