# Community promotion ad with books and references

Tags: discussion, references

We maintain [list of web pages, tutorials and help forums about statistical software](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that has its own [community promotion ad](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/community-promotion-ads-2015), in my opinion it is nice idea to explicitly provide such links. But maybe we should go one step further and also create a meta-list of links to different *threads about books, online courses and other study materials*. Such questions appear very often and often get duplicated, so maintaining single meta-list could help to build a single references repository similar to the software one. Community promotion ad would make it easier to find such page. This is not exactly consistent with SE policy on long lists etc., but maybe in this case it is not that bad idea..? What do you think?

Comment: How would this meta-list differ from the tags?  For instance, if you click through [tag:books] you will get a list of all threads about books in a searchable format.

Comment: @whuber yes but still each week there is at least one thread about looking for books that duplicates multiple others, so maybe we should have something more than this.

Comment: Could you explain what the "more" would be?

Comment: This is an opportunity to discuss about recommendation of references and try to advance with the internal policy on this matter. In the earlies of CV, recommendation lists were welcomed; gradually they started to be marked as community wiki. Nowadays, it seems that only questions which are well asked (going beyond "what is best reading for x"?) are welcome. I think except for these ones, all the other should be closed from now on as opinion-based. But it would be nice if someone could make a review in our meta to raise all past discussions and put together in one answer.

Comment: @whuber I meant higher accessibility. Obviously to find the [tag:boos] you just have to search through the tagged questions, but it is exactly the same with software questions -- you just have to read the help page to learn that they are off-topic. Problem is that people in general do not do this. Providing easier access to such list could help in here. We could also make new **close reason that redirects to such list**. I also agree with Andre, that maybe we should change our policy about books questions.